# Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors...in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-package

Error:

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04063: package body "P12284.EMP_DESIGNATION" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"P12284.EMP_DESIGNATION"
ORA-06512: at line 2

**How to solve This ? Please Help me I'm New to PL/SQL**

`

```
set serveroutput on;
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EMP_DESIGNATION 
    AS
    PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS(PS_design employee.designation%TYPE, PS_incentive number);
    END EMP_DESIGNATION;
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EMP_DESIGNATION
    AS
    PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS(design employee.designation%TYPE, incentive number)
    IS
    BEGIN
        update employee set employee.salary = employee.salary + incentive where designation = design ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' employee(s) are updated');
         
    END;
    /
    `
```

Comment: Hello Ankit, debugging pl/sql packages on the command line is a challenge. I suggest you use a tool like SQL Developer (which is free) and makes your life a lot easier when it comes to locating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end your package body too -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EMP_DESIGNATION
AS
    PROCEDURE EMP_DETAILS(design employee.designation%TYPE, incentive number)
    IS
    BEGIN
        update employee set employee.salary = employee.salary + incentive where designation = design ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' employee(s) are updated');
         
    END;
END EMP_DESIGNATION;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems,

1. The signature of the `emp_details` should match in both spec and body
2. You forgot to `end` the procedure in package body.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_designation AS
   PROCEDURE emp_details
     (
       ps_design    employee.designation%TYPE
     , ps_incentive NUMBER
     );
   END emp_designation;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_designation AS
     PROCEDURE emp_details
       ( 
         ps_design employee.designation%TYPE
       , ps_incentive NUMBER
       ) 
     IS
     BEGIN
       UPDATE employee SET employee.salary = employee.salary + ps_incentive 
         WHERE designation = ps_design; 
       dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' employee(s) are updated');
     END emp_details;
   END;
   /
   ```

Comment: **Thanks a Lot....!!!** To spend ur valuable time to had a look on my prob....

Comment: No problem :). If it solved your problem you can accept the answer and give it a tick :)